# Visual C++ 2005 hangs during qt builds

Tags: c++, qt, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

At my shop, the main product app is a mongrel built on MFC, QT and other random things devs have thrown in over the years.
In the current stack, Qt toolkit is on the way out, but still features heavily.

If I have SQL 2005 Management studio open and have to do a full build, it usually hangs a CPU (even after the offending process is taken out back and shot...) during the qt specific parts of the build (Moc'ing and UIC'ing)

has anyone seen anything like this? any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, some of these tools are capable of looping forever (qt4: lupdate/lrelease for sure).

Comment: yeah, it looks like it was stumbling on a particular file, nothing to do with SQL....
I'll keep an eye on this. the odd thing is the core hanging even after the UIC process is killed, on a different process